# Python: Loop through folders, convert XLSX files to CSV removing non ASCII

Tags: python, performance

As the subject suggests:

- Loop recursively through folders
- All files are XLSX
- Remove all non ASCII characters
- Save as a CSV

Can it be improved with regards to speed? Would using `openpyxl` help?

```
import os
import xlrd
import csv

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\Users\Alan\Downloads\Knowledge"):
    for file in files:
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file

        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath)
        sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
        csv_file = open(filepath.replace(".xlsx","")+'_csv.csv','wb')
        wr = csv.writer(csv_file,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
            wr.writerow([unicode(val).encode('ascii','ignore') for val in sh.row_values(rownum)])

        csv_file.close()
```

Comment: How do you target the first worksheet though? Tried a few ways but it seems the only way is to iterate through all worksheets.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have a couple of *suggestions* which you may want to follow:

1. Use `openpyxl` module to read xlsx documents, and the `csv` module to write.

An example might look like this:

```
import openpyxl
import csv

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sh = wb.get_active_sheet()
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    c = csv.writer(f)
    for r in sh.rows:
        # here, you can also filter non-ascii characters
        c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
```

2. Don't use `os.sep`.

From docs:

> [...] Note that knowing this is not sufficient to be able to parse or
>   concatenate path names...

Instead, you could use `normpath` from `os.path` to normalize the path.

From the docs:

> Normalize a pathname by collapsing redundant separators and up-level
>   references so that `A//B`, `A/B/`, `A/./B` and `A/foo/../B` all become `A/B`.
>   This string manipulation may change the meaning of a path that
>   contains symbolic links. On Windows, it converts forward slashes to
>   backward slashes.

3. Don't use `+` separator to join certain paths. Instead, just use `os.path.join()`.

As for the speed improvement, you'll need to go through all the subfolders in your parent folder and find all the .xslx files. Perhaps skipping *non-xlsx* files will bring a bit of speed: `str.endswith('.xslx')`.